# form.is_valid() が常にFlaseになる

Tags: python, django

form.is_valid() が常にFlaseになってしまいます。

forms.pyに

```
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('image',)
```

と書きました。なぜいつもform.is_valid() がFlaseになるのでしょうか？どう直せば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！ Flase でなく False でしょうか。

Comment: `form.is_valid()` を実行している部分のソースコードを追記して頂くことは可能ですか？　また、`form.errors` の中身はどうなっていますでしょうか。